# Python can't open image with indirect url

Tags: python, image, download

I use python to download image, if url is direct to image that I can download them, but if it is indirect, only black image is opened, what can I do next?

Success downloaded

```
https://secure-api.userlocal.jp/ipcamera/posts/files/16/41/502241_2017022116205643436_830aaf54751.jpg
```

Failed download

```
http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg
```

Comment: well that second url **is** a black image. So you need to be more specfic.

Comment: What do you mean? I can view it in browser, but it can't be saved, can you help me? I used code as Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(urlServer)).convert('RGB').save(pathLocal)

Comment: so you **can** download the black image but can't save it? if that is the case then I am not sure without seeing more of your code.

Comment: sorry my English is not so good enough, the original image is not black, it is a normal image that I can view it in browser, but after save it that is only black, may I make sense?

Comment: Well, I got what I need with save_screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Use save_screenshot or get_screenshot_as_base64()